# Double clicking "Delete" vote deletes next LQ post as well

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-queues, low-quality-posts

In the Low Quality Posts review queue, when clicking "Recommend Deletion", selecting a reason, and then clicking "Delete" twice quickly, the next review will be vote deleted as well.

Apparently sometimes my finger likes to double click (perhaps a reflex like, oh, I missed the button, let's try again!).
This happened a little while back, and I thought nothing of it, should not occur very often. Obviously it just happened again :)

Running `Chrome 36.0.1985.125 m` on `Windows 8.1 Pro`.

---

I had deleted this question because I could not reproduce it anymore. However, I "voted" to delete [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5475383) as a result of double clicking the delete button for [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5475384).
If you hover over the timestamps, you can see that the votes are both cast at exactly the same second (`2014-08-06 09:19:26Z`).

So, since I've found my proof, I can finally stop doubleclicking and potentially vote to delete 'OK' posts :)

Comment: Unable to reproduce it here, when I really click twice fast on the delete, it skips a review without casting a vote. Tried 3 times and all the time this is how it acted. No double vote. If I use `Go back one page` in Firefox, if I acted on the review, it shows that while it doesn't on the second post with double click.

Comment: Hmm, cannot test again due to lack of posts in the queue, but I thought when pressing back, it would say that I had already reviewed the post with a recommend deletion.

Comment: Ok, I'm on `Mint cinnamon 17` with Firefox... I'll blame Windows.

Comment: And of course, now when trying again, I've hit my 20 review limit..

Comment: I've had this problem too several times, although it's sufficiently sporadic I'd blamed myself :/. [Arch Linux, Google Chrome, i3.]

Comment: @Veedrac I did too. Apparently it's not *that* sporadic :)

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203086/accidental-triggering-of-recommend-deletion-button-on-vlq-queue and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222474/race-condition-in-low-quality-audit

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy Ah yes. I hasn't been picked up though.

Comment: I just had this happen as well to this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/6046275) by voting to delete the previous review (http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/6046085)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We've been seeing some exceptions about users suggesting to delete questions in the low quality queue for a while now. Turns out it was just another symptom of this bug, when the next review item is a question instead of an answer, as one can only suggest to close a question. Thanks for bringing me on the right track.

The fix will be going out with build rev `2014.12.18.2122`.